# Rancher can not access the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I use Rancher to access the cluster , but the access failed and an error was reported:

```
Cluster health check failed: Failed to communicate with API server: Get "https://172.20.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system?timeout=45s": context deadline exceeded.
Error Get "https://172.20.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?timeout=45s": waiting for cluster [c-9dbht] agent to connect.
```

I located that cattle-cluster-agent is in crashLoopBackOff state and reported the following error:

```
error msg="failed to unmarshal https://releases.rancher.com/index.yaml: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type repo.IndexFile".
level=error msg="error syncing 'rancher-latest': handler helm-clusterrepo-download: failed to parse response from https://releases.rancher.com/index.yaml, requeuing".
Observed a panic: runtime.boundsError{x:3, y:0, signed:true, code:0x2} (runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:3] with capacity 0).
```

The cattle-cluster-agent's container is constantly being restarted.

Anyone knows how to solve it?